# How to fix my error when trying to update on vmware kali?

Tags: permissions, apt, kali-linux, upgrade

I have Vmware workstation player 15 installed Kali Linux 2020.1.

When I try to update on vmware kali I'm getting this error:

```
Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

I have also tried the `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/` command but it does not work either, it gives me this error:

```
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/apt/lists/': Is a directory.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You may have

- forgotten to run apt with sudo
- a stale lock file. Remove it with

  ```
  sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
  ```